# Creating a new array of numbers based on an existing string array

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of values that correlate to a string by comparing each character of my string to that of my "alpha_list". This is for encoding procedure so that the numerical values can be added later.

I keep getting multiple errors from numerous different ways i have tried to make this happen.

```
import string

alpha_list = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
ints = "HELLO WORLD"
myotherlist = []

for idx, val in enumerate(ints):
    myotherlist[idx] = alpha_list.index(val)

print(myotherlist)
```

Right now this is my current error reading

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Derek/Desktop/Python/test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    myotherlist[idx] = alpha_list.index(val)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I am pretty new to python so if I am making a ridiculously obvious mistake please feel free to criticize.

The print(myotherlist) output that i am looking for should look something like this:

[8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 0, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]

Comment: Just to be clear i am trying to shorten the format where i list every single letter and assign a number in if and elif statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use append:

```
for  val in ints:
    myotherlist.append(alpha_list.index(val))
print(myotherlist)
```

`myotherlist` is an empty list so you cannot access using `myotherlist[idx]` as there is no element 0 etc..

Or just use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_other_list = [alpha_list.index(val) for val in ints]
```

Or a functional approach using map:

```
map(alpha_list.index,ints))
```

Both output:

```
In [7]: [alpha_list.index(val) for val in ints]
Out[7]: [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 0, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]

In [8]: map(alpha_list.index,ints)
Out[8]: [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 0, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]
```

Comment: my_other_list = [alpha_list.index(val) for val in ints]  is what im going to go with, thank you very much!  I had tried this approach and i even thought i tried your first approach, but i think i had used () instead of [] again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. `import string` - don't use that a bunch of books say its better to use the built in str
2. `myotherlist[idx] = alpha_list.index(val)` is why you are getting the error. This is saying 'Go to `idx` index and put `alpha_list.index(val)` there, but since the list is empty it cannot do that.

So if you replace

```
for idx, val in enumerate(ints):
    myotherlist[idx] = alpha_list.index(val)
```

with

```
for letter in ints:  #iterates over the 'HELLO WORLD' string
    index_to_append = alpha_list.index(letter)
    myotherlist.append(index_to_append)
```

you will get the expected result!
If there is something not clear please let me know!

Comment: where does it say not to use the string module?

Comment: Well i dont recall the names (I would of stated them otherwise), but I remember reading that the string module was used with earlier versions of python for some functions that would later be implemented as built in methods of the str. So there is no real reason to use that module and as a beginner who doesn't know that the difference or the lack of  it would be confusing. So don't use that

Comment: that is not correct, the string module is still used and has many methods and attributes that are not contained in the str module

Comment: I never said it is not used ...
help(string) states:
Warning: most of the code you see here isn't normally used nowadays.
    Beginning with Python 1.6, many of these functions are implemented as
    methods on the standard string object. They used to be implemented by
    a built-in module called strop, but strop is now obsolete itself.

Comment: what does **import string - don't use that a bunch of books say its better to use the built in str** mean?

Comment: Yes i had been using the earlier 2.x version and only today switched to the 3.4 so this is good to know i may not need that